# Get N value from database mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table i get cars form databases and i list it in this table:

```
$row_id=$_GET["id"];
$solK = ($row_id-1) * 9;
$sagK = ($row_id) * 9;
$sorgu2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Car WHERE Car_ID > '$solK' AND Car_ID < '$sagK'");
```

Every page have 9 cars i use id for sort these cars but when i delete a car (for example Carid=5) in first page have 8 cars but other pages have 9 cars how can i get first N values without CarId from databases can you explain with sql codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limit-optimization.html) to your query.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 0, 9
```

will select the first 9 entries from `tbl`.

In order to match your query and preserve the ordering I'd state it as

```
SELECT * FROM Car ORDER BY Car_ID LIMIT 0, 9
```

for the first nine rows. For the next nine rows, just increment both numbers by 10 and so on.

Comment: Using either of the supplied answers you could still `ORDER BY Car_ID` to maintain your ordering

Answer (score 2):

Rather than code it like you have done, just use LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM Car LIMIT 0,9
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM Car LIMIT 9,9
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the other answers (using limit and offset) will be suited for your case. But if you (or anyone else) ever need to improve performance, and need to manage fast queries for more than the first few pages, you should implement paging like this:

```
  SELECT f1, f2, ... 
    FROM tbl
      WHERE Car_ID > $id
    ORDER BY Car_ID
    LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "LIMIT offset, row_count"  in you statement

Try this SQL statement `SELECT * FROM Car LIMIT '$pageN*$nperpage', '$nperpage'`

Where `$nperpage` will be a number of items per page and `$pageN` will be a page number (note that in this case page numbering starts with 0).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html